# What is holometer experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, universe

According to [official website](https://holometer.fnal.gov/)

> The Fermilab Holometer is a new kind of instrument designed to study
>   the quantum character of space itself. It measures the quantum
>   coherence of location with unprecedented precision.

What is the purpose of this experiment? Is it for proving or disproving [simulation-hypothesis](http://www.simulation-argument.com/)!. What is the principle behind this experiment?

*(Not from mathemtial background)*

Comment: The official website explains the purpose in a few sentences. Why do you think there is a connection with the "Are you living in a Computer Simulation?" article?

Comment: I consider myself to have at least a moderate background in physics, and the in-article explanation likewise leaves me dissatisfied. I'd recommend the [FAQs](https://holometer.fnal.gov/faq.html#logo), and go from there.

Comment: What would be a lot more physical and of value, instead of this non-mainstream are we living in a simulation (or are you simply simulating this exchange of words, I don't think I have a chip inside me, so not of interest to me) is whether the holometer can detect what are essentially Planck spacetime fluctuations. Better than a Nobel. . I read their web pages, and there is physics going on, but I can not quite decide if I accept their conclusions. The theory of it described is very skimpy. I will look more into whether it's believable